# How to find the area of the image of the unit disc?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

> Let $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ be defined by $$f(x,y)=(x+y,2x+ay)$$
> Please examine the image of the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, when $a=1,2$ and find the area of the image of the unit disc $x^2+y^2\le 1$ when $a=3$.

For $a=1,2,3$, $f$ is a linear transformation.

When $a=1$, $f(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&1\\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$ and $\text{Im}f=\{x(1,1)+y(2,1):x,y\in[0,1]\times[0,1]\}$.

When $a=2$, $f(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&2\\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$ and $\text{Im}f=\{(x+2y)(1,1):x,y\in[0,1]\times[0,1]\}$.

But I have no idea how to find the area of the image of the unit disc $x^2+y^2\le 1$ when $a=3$. Appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear transformation. The areas are multiplied by the Jacobian (the determinant of the transformation) which is $1$. So the area remains the same, equal to $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer